# move and rename file in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, image-uploading, symfony-2.4

I am learning Symfony2, and I am trying to upload an image from a handmade form to a destination folder, but changing its name before.

I think the easiest method is with:

```
move_uploaded_file(actual_file, destination_with_new_name)
```

But I get the following error message:

```
ContextErrorException: Warning: move_uploaded_file(http://localhost/PublisherMyAdmin/web/app_dev.php/imagenesportadas/1.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in C:\xampp\htdocs\PublisherMyAdmin\src\ochodoscuatro\IntranetBundle\Controller\MaterialesController.php line 163
```

My code is:

```
$dir =  $this->getRequest()->getUriForPath('/imagenesportadas/');
$nombre = $id.".".$extension;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"], $dir.$nombre)) {

    echo "Thank you for uploading your music!<br /><br />";

} else {

    echo "Your file did not upload.<br /><br />";

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Symfony2 way of doing this would be similar to the following:

You can get uploaded files from the [request object](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html), by accessing the `files` property.
Given you are in a controller context:

```
// get the request object
$request = $this->get('request');

// retrieve uploaded files
$files = $request->files;

// and store the file
$uploadedFile = $files->get('archivo');
$file = $uploadedFile->move($directory, $name);
```

By calling `get` on the [`FileBag`](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/FileBag.html) object in `$files`, you get an instance of [`UploadedFile`](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html), which provides a method [`move`](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_move), to store and rename the temporary file.

You get the error message because you're using an HTTP location instead of a filesystem path. Try to store the files somewhere in the `web/` folder, for example:

```
$directory = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/../web/uploads/imagenesportadas';
```

Comment: Thank you! It is hard to get all the Symfony2 logic... You have solved my day.